# Error when using helm: module 'glib' has no attribute 'get_user_config_dir'

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install the ingress-nginx controller via helm. When I run the install command on the [Kubernetes website](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#environment-specific-instructions), I get the error "module 'glib' has no attribute 'get_user_config_dir".

```
helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/helm", line 42, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/helm", line 28, in main
    config_dirs = (glib.get_user_config_dir(),) + glib.get_system_config_dirs()
AttributeError: module 'glib' has no attribute 'get_user_config_dir'
```

I get a similar error when I just run helm on its own.

```
$ helm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/helm", line 42, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/helm", line 28, in main
    config_dirs = (glib.get_user_config_dir(),) + glib.get_system_config_dirs()
AttributeError: module 'glib' has no attribute 'get_user_config_dir'
```

How can I set the attribute get_user_config_dir so that helm installs the ingress-nginx controller?

---

Edit:

I'm updating this question to show the version of glib I am using.

```
$ pip3 show glib
Name: glib
Version: 1.0.0
Summary: A python graphics library that piggy-backs off of pyqt5
Home-page: UNKNOWN
Author: its_me
Author-email: rycepie3909@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

Comment: What version of glib is installed?

Comment: @smac89 I'm using version 1.0.0 of glib

Comment: No that's not the glib I'm speaking of. The error is concerned with GLib aka [Gnome Lib](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/). [`get_user_config_dir`](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/func.get_user_config_dir.html) is available from GLib version 2.6. What I wanted to know was what version of glib is installed on your system. First, you may need to install some [libraries](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#macosx-logo-macos) for mac, then open a python terminal and try `from gi.repository import GLib; GLib.check_version(2,6,0)`, to see if your version is compatible.

Comment: Also the `helm` program you are using, where is that obtained from? I'm not sure they are checking properly for GLib seeing as they are using [`glib`](https://pypi.org/project/glib/), which I don't think will have anything to do with gtk, nor is it open source. That's very sus. Also [helm](https://github.com/helm/helm) is written in Golang, so it's kinda confusing that they are importing a python library. Please verify that the programs you are running are the ones you should be running

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem when running helm via ansible.

I checked the helm module I installed. It turned out I installed the wrong [helm](https://pypi.org/project/helm/) module:
**Helm is a system monitor released under GNU GPLv3.**

Instead I had to install [helm-python](https://pypi.org/project/helm-python/):

```
pip install helm-python
```

Hope this helps

Regards!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer I thought I was going crazy, this is so hard to spot in a big Ansible playbook !